# Full-state controllability and pole-zero cancellation

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

In trying to derive a control law for a linear system so as to make it track a reference signal, I came up with the following and ended up with a few question. Let the following be the dynamic equation of a linear system, where $x$ is the output and $u$ the input:

$$x^{(n)}+a_{n-1}x^{(n-1)}+\dots+a_0x=u$$

We wish to determine some control law $u$ so that $x$ will track some reference signal $r$. Define the error $e=x-r$. Now we have $x=e+r$. The dynamics of the new system whose output is $e$ are given by:

$$e^{(n)}+a_{n-1}e^{(n-1)}+\dots+a_0e=u-r^{(n)}-a_{n-1}r^{(n-1)}\dots-a_0r$$

Let $u$ be

$$u=-K_{n-1}e^{(n-1)}-K_{n-2}e^{(n-2)}-\dots-K_{0}e+r^{(n)}+r^{(n-1)}+\dots+r$$

Making the substitution, we get

$$e^{(n)}+(a_{n-1}+K_{n-1})e^{(n-1)}+\dots+(a_0+K_0)e^{(n)}=0$$

As can be seen, the dynamics of the error don't depend on the particular reference signal, only on the initial conditions. Taking the Laplace Transform and assuming zero initial conditions:

$$E(s^n+(a_{n-1}+K_{n-1})s^{n-1}+\dots+a_0+K_0)=0$$

So that $E=0$, i.e., if the initial conditions are of zero error, the error will remain zero.

Substituting these results back into the original equation, we get

$$x^{(n)}+(a_{n-1}+K_{n-1})x^{(n-1)}+\dots+(a_0+K_0)x=r^{(n)}+(a_{n-1}+K_{n-1})r^{(n-1)}+\dots+(a_0+K_0)r$$

Taking Laplace Transforms and assuming zero initial conditions, we obtain the transfer function of the system:

$$\frac{X}{R}=\frac{s^n+(a_{n-1}+K_{n-1})s^{n-1}+\dots+a_o+K_0}{s^n+(a_{n-1}+K_{n-1})s^{n-1}+\dots+a_o+K_0}$$

As expected, the numerator and denominator cancel entirely, giving us $\frac{X}{R}=1$, which, once again, indicates that if the system has zero initial error, it will always have zero error, as $x$ will track $r$ perfectly.

My question is how this relates to the controllability of the system for the input $r$. From what I've learned, if there is any pole-zero cancellation in the transfer function of a system, the system isn't controllable along the cancelled mode. Since everything cancelled out in this case, I'd assume that would mean nothing could be controlled. However, conceptually, it seems, by definition of the results, as if we can make the system reach any state we'd like with a suitable input $r$: given any initial condition $x_0$, let $r$ be an adequately differentiable signal whose value and whose derivates up to order $n-1$ are the same as those of the output at $t_0$, and that eventually reaches $r(t_1)=0$, $r\dot(t_1)=0$, $\dots$, $r^{(n-1)}(t_1)=0$ at some time $t_1$. Being able to find a suitable $r$, the system would be controllable. Why does the contradiction arise?

Comment: The system with input $r$ is not controllable, this can be easily checked from any of the controllability criterion. Controllability means that you can place all the states to any value at any time independently of the others, this is not the case here. But this is not your point here as your goal is not to control the full state $(x^{(n)},\ldots,x)$ but just $x$. In fact, if the output of your system is $y=x$, then this system is output-controllable.

Comment: @KBS But isn't it true that we can control $x$ and every derivative of it of order up to $n-1$? Suppose $\mathbf X(t_0)=(x_0,\dot {x_0},\dots\,x^{(n-1)}_0)$ at time $t_0$. To show controllability, we should be able to make the system reach the origin for any of those $\mathbf X(t_0)$ in finite time, say $t_1$. Let $r$ be a polynomial of degree $2n-1$. Now we have $2n$ coefficients to determine from the state at $t_0$ and the state at $t_1$, so that $r(t_0)=x_0$, $\dot r(t_0)=\dot {x_0}$, $\dots$, $r^{(n-1)}(t_0)=x^{(n-1)}_0$ and $r(t_1)=0$, $\dot r(t_1)=0$, $\dots$, $r^{(n-1)}(t_1)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you asked. I have written an answer, please comment it.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no zero-pole cancellations in the transfer function of a single-input single-output system, then the system is both controllable and observable. If a zero-pole cancellation occurs, then the system is either uncontrollable or unobservable or both uncontrollable and unobservable.

There are two possible state-space representations for the transfer function you are considering. The first one is the observable canonical form given by

$$\dot{x}_o(t)=A_ox_o(t),\quad y(t)=e_{n}^Tx_o(t)+r(t)$$

whereas the second one is the controllable canonical form

$$\dot{x}_c(t)=A_cx_c(t)+e_{n}r(t),\quad y(t)=r(t).$$

The first realization is observable but completely uncontrollable whereas the second one is controllable but completely unobservable.

In both cases, under zero initial conditions, we get that the transfer is simply $y(t)=r(t)$.

Comment: I think I might have a misunderstanding of what goes into defining state variables. From what I know, with a knowledge of the state variables at a given time, the dynamics of the system and the input at that time and at every time thereafter, we should be able to precisely determine where the system will be at a future time. Is it implied here that the input alone is what is known, and that the derivatives of the input are assumed to be unknown?

Comment: I had written an answer, but I have removed it because i think this answer suffices. @jvf It boils down to realizations. That result should be referring to the combined state-space model for two (controllable & observable) cascade state-space models of the controller and plant forming a total state-space model. In your case, your controller doesn't have a state-space model (it is not a proper TF) so the result doesn't apply. Your controller is state-less, and involves a (high-order) feedforward.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza I'm sorry, I'm not quite certain of the meaning of some of those terms. Is "realization" a synonym for "representation", as in a state-space representation? Is the result you're referring to the one I obtained or the one that asserts that cancellations in the transfer function entail a lack of controllability? What does it mean for something to be stateless? Do you have a reference on this subject I can look up in more detail?

Comment: @jvf. yes: state-space representation. Oops, I did erase a sentence there. "The result" refers to the fact that cancellations in cascade TFs => loss of controllability/observability in any representation of the combined systems. State-less was colloquial. Earlier in the comment I say there is no state-space model describing your controller. The formal issue with your controller is that it is *non-causal* as an ideal differentiator appears in it. Maybe see Chp. 3 of Hespanha's Linear System Theory. Causality is touched on by many linear system theory books as its required for a well-defined TF.